# How to globally set all electron apps to have --enable-features=UseOzonePlatform --ozone-platform=wayland options?

Tags: arch-linux, configuration, environment-variables, wayland

I switched to wayland on arch linux and it introduced a lot of bugs. Many are related to electron apps. I have find out that I can solve them by starting apps with this options:

```
--enable-features=UseOzonePlatform --ozone-platform=wayland
```

but I also use rofi to open my apps or they are opened automatically by user scripts.

Is there way to set these options globally to all electron apps ? Is there electron config file where I can set these options ?

Thank you for help

---

EDIT:
I have found this bug which causes this issues: [bugs.archlinux.org/task/75667](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/75667)

Comment: Yes, you can use a file, see https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Wayland#Configuration_file

Comment: This doesn't actually work.

Answer (score 0):

Set the [environment variable](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/main/docs/api/environment-variables.md#electron_ozone_platform_hint-linux) `ELECTRON_OZONE_PLATFORM_HINT` to `auto`, added in Electron 28.

Comment: This tells electron to use Wayland, if possible.   From the question, it appears that it is *already* using Wayland.  Why do you believe that your suggestion will solve the OP’s problem?

Comment: **From the question, it appears that it is already using Wayland**

It doesn't. If in doubt, read the documentation I linked.

**Why do you believe that your suggestion will solve the OP’s problem?**

I have read the linked documentation.